# AppleScript to record webcam video

Tags: applescript, webcam

I am new to AppleScript and trying to write a script to record from webcam for say X seconds.

The script below gives an error that I do not have permission to save this file to Desktop. How can I avoid this error?

Secondly how can I save the file with Date and Time stamp appended in the name of the file?

```
tellapplication "QuickTime Player"  
  set newMovieRecording to new movie recording  

  tell newMovieRecording  
  start  
  delay 5  
  pause  
  save newMovieRecording in "/users/rohitbhutani/desktop/movie.mov"  
  stop  
  close newMovieRecording  
  end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone at Apple communities helped me resolve the issue. Posting an answer if someone faces the same issue.

```
 set theCurrentDate to current date
set dateTime to short date string of theCurrentDate & space & time string of theCurrentDate
set P to offset of "/" in dateTime
set dateTime to text 1 through (P - 1) of dateTime & "-" & text (P + 1) through -1 of dateTime
set P to offset of "/" in dateTime
set dateTime to text 1 through (P - 1) of dateTime & "-" & text (P + 1) through -1 of dateTime
set theFilePath to "/Users/rohitbhutani/Desktop/movie " & dateTime & ".mov"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
     set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
     tell newMovieRecording
           start
           delay 5
           pause
           save newMovieRecording in POSIX file theFilePath
           stop
           close newMovieRecording
     end tell
end tell
```